# Can't debug KDevelop with KDevelop in Gnome shell

Tags: debugging, kdevelop, gnome-shell

This problem may sound quite funny, but it's actually quite annoying.

It happens when I start debugging the KDevelop source code in KDevelop: when the debugged app hits the breakpoint and stops, I go to the main app and start working, but soon it becomes unresponsive. Switching to the debugged instance I always find the Gnome's "app doesn't respond" message which offers me to kill an app or wait a little. If I choose "kill", the debugged app closes and the main one continues working, and if I choose "wait" the main instance of IDE unfreezes until the message appears again.

From what I understand, the "kill or wait" message freezes the main app too, for some reason, but it doesn't happen each time I run debugging, so the problem is really quite strange.

I use: Ubuntu 18.04.1, Gnome Shell 3.28.2, KDevelop 5.2.3

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed a bug.
You may want to report it here: https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=kdevelop
You also may get helped in our IRC channel #kdevelop at Freenode ([join via web chat here](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=kdevelop)).

> If you're unfamiliar with IRC please read on general IRC guide lines (netiquette) [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/Guidelines). In particular note: People may not have an answer to your question right away, so please be patient. In IRC terms, this might mean five minutes, but could also be 2-3 hours or more.

Comment: I don't think that it's KDE bug, because everything works smoothly in Plasma.

Comment: @vchslv13 ah, ok, I see. Try to start some program with gdb from the gnome shell and see if the effect is still there